# Why does this onClick event not work in an HTML iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

I am trying to use an onClick event to register when a user has clicked on an iframe. Why doesn't this work?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8wropLmb/13/)

Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>

function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
}
</script>
</head>

<body onLoad="def()">
<iframe id="myFrame" border="0" onclick="myFunction()"></iframe>
<p id="demo"></p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: click event will trigger only when you click on the border of iframe not inside it

Comment: You would have to bind a listener to the page inside of the iframe. (I am sure there are dupes on this one)

Comment: I won't be able to add a listener on the inside page because it links to another site. Is there anyway I can detect when someone clicks on the iframe without covering up the iframe with something like a span?

Comment: I need something like this but for multiple iframes with different ids jsfiddle.net/oqjgzsm0

Comment: What you are trying to do is not possible if you do not have CORS access to the page loaded in the iframe

Answer (score 1):

If the iframe is from your own site, you can write:

```
document.getElementById("myFrame")
    .contentWindow.document.body
    .onclick = function() {
        alert("iframe clicked");
    }
```

The code however will not work if the iframe is from different domain than the host page.

Comment: Unfortunately I do not host or own the page inside the iframe so capturing it will have to be done from the same page as the iframe tag.

Comment: I need something like this but for multiple iframes with different ids http://jsfiddle.net/oqjgzsm0/

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether this works with websites without CORS or whatever, but for what I needed this worked with multiple iframes with different IDs -
 https://jsfiddle.net/ab0a/1fyoajqc/6/

```
<!-- Multiple iframes with different IDs -->
<iframe id="iframe" src="https://livestream.com/accounts/5690925/events/6124324/player?width=960&height=540&enableInfoAndActivity=true&defaultDrawer=feed&autoPlay=true&mute=false" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe id="iframetwo" src="iframe/here/too" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<iframe id="iframethree" src="iframe/here/as/well" width="960" height="540" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" allowfullscreen></iframe>
<div id="message"></div>

<script>
var monitor = setInterval(function() {
  var elem = document.activeElement;
  if (elem.id == 'iframe') {
    message.innerHTML = 'One';
    //use clearInterval(monitor); if you want to stop checking
    //clearInterval(monitor);
  }
  if (elem.id == 'iframetwo') {
    message.innerHTML = 'Two';
    //clearInterval(monitor);
  }
}, 100);

/* If you only want to check for a specific iframe once, but still want to check for others, set up another monitor for that specific iframe */
var monitorTwo = setInterval(function() {
  var elemTwo = document.activeElement;
  if (elemTwo.id == 'iframethree') {
    message.innerHTML = 'Three';
    message.style = 'background-color: red;';
    clearInterval(monitorTwo);
  }
})
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

this worker for me, in CSS

```
.thumbnail .item iframe{
position: absolute ; 
inset:0; 
pointer-events: none;}



.thumbnail .item.active iframe{
pointer-events: auto !important;}
```

Now the iframes in the thumbnails are clickeable and all iframe buttons within the entire area of tge iframe and when iframe is clicked, the clickable event works by moving the carrousel (this were my 2 requirements)

The clickable event , is in the app.js file

```
   ' // click thumbnail
     thumbnails.forEach((thumbnail, index) => {
     thumbnail.addEventListener('click', () => {
    itemActive = index;
    showSlider();
    })
    })'
```

just ensure pointer-events: none; is remove from the thumbnail iframe active and make it auto

Answer (score -1):

I had more luck with the following JS:

```
document.getElementById("myFrame").contentWindow.onclick = 
        function() {
            alert("iframe clicked");
        }
```

Comment: I tried it. Didn't work.